# Dynamic light box in jsp pages

Tags: jsp, dynamic, lightbox

My question is about the dynamically creation of a light box if some condition is true in many jsp pages.
For an example I have 200 jsp pages and I want to add a light box to be shown in only 50 of them. To made this I can use the web.xml or the database.
The light box will be created in a separate jsp page as a modul.
So how can I create dynamic light box with functionality on individual page depending on some condition retrieved from the web.xml or the database?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you storing these pages in the database? Interesting scenario though and I appreciate the fact that you are looking for something generic.

Comment: no. The database is only suggestion for storing the urls of the pages there.